# How to avoid unnecessary match checks or using unsafe while moving a value from a structure that implements Drop?

Tags: rust, destructor, unsafe

I have the structure `B` that implements the trait `Trait` with the method `do_something`. I need to perform some additional actions when struct `B` is dropped if this function has not been called. Specifically, if `do_something` was never called, `Vec<A>` should be filled with `A::None`:

```rust
enum A {
    V1,
    V2,
    None,
}

struct B {
    data: Option<(A, Vec<A>)>,
}

trait Trait {
    fn do_something(self) -> Vec<A>;
}

impl Trait for B {
    fn do_something(mut self) -> Vec<A> {
        let (a, mut vec) = self.data.take().unwrap();
        vec.push(a);
        vec
    }
}

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match self.data.take() {
            Some((a, mut vec)) => vec.push(A::None),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

This has some logically unnecessary `match` checks. I want to avoid them and came up with the following solution:

```rust
struct B {
    data: (A, Vec<A>),
}

trait Trait {
    fn do_something(self) -> Vec<A>;
}

impl Trait for B {
    fn do_something(mut self) -> Vec<A> {
        let (a, mut vec) = std::mem::replace(&mut self.data, unsafe {
            std::mem::MaybeUninit::<(A, Vec<A>)>::uninit().assume_init()
        });
        std::mem::forget(self);
        vec.push(a);
        vec
    }
}

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.data.1.push(A::None)
    }
}
```

1. Is my `unsafe` solution correct? Does it contain undefined behavior?
2. Is it possible to avoid using either `unsafe` or wrapping `B.data` in `Option` to achieve the above behavior?

Comment: The current code seems correct, but also fragile - if you ever introduce something that accesses `self.data` before `forget(self)`, you'll have UB. Also, `MaybeUninit::uninit()::assume_init()` has a definite code smell to it. Since an empty vector [doesn't allocate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) and `A` has a cheap `None` variant, why not use `mem::replace(&mut self.data, (A::None, vec![]))`? There should be no run-time cost, no unsafe, and the code no longer serves as attractor for UB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will trigger UB (Rustc also emits a warning), because uninitialized memory is written into `self.data`. Please read [std::mem::replace()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) carefully.

Comment: I appreciate that you've created a [MRE], but I think it's possible that you are suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281829). It's unclear why you need to fill the vector with *anything* in order to drop it, which suggests that there's a better way to do what you want, if you step back some.

Comment: I second Shepmaster; what is the point of `push(A::None)` on a `Vec` that is being destructed? I am afraid your example has been simplified too far.

Answer (score 0):

This not only moves the values out of the struct, it also writes uninitialized memory *into* the struct. The compiler warns that this will cause undefined behavior:

```
warning: the type `(A, std::vec::Vec<A>)` does not permit being left uninitialized
  --> src/main.rs:21:22
   |
21 |             unsafe { std::mem::MaybeUninit::<(A, Vec<A>)>::uninit().assume_init() },
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      this code causes undefined behavior when executed
   |                      help: use `MaybeUninit<T>` instead, and only call `assume_init` after initialization is done
   |
   = note: `#[warn(invalid_value)]` on by default
note: std::ptr::Unique<A> must be non-null (in this struct field)
```

A better solution is to use `mem::transmute()`:

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct B {
    data: (A, Vec<A>),
}

impl Trait for B {
    fn do_something(self) -> Vec<A> {
        // Safety: Since `B` is transparent, `B` and (A, Vec<A>) have the same size and layout.
        let (a, mut vec): (A, Vec<A>) = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self) };
        vec.push(a);
        vec
    }
}
```

Note that this prevents `Drop` from being called. If the `Drop` implementation frees memory or other resources, you have to do this manually.